# SQL create table and set auto increment value without Alter table

Tags: mysql, create-table

For example I am creating the following table:

> CREATE TABLE Persons (
>  
>        ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  
>        LastName
>   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>  
>        FirstName varchar(255),
>        Address varchar(255), 
>        PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
> )

As I know, the value of Auto increment can be modify by Alter table like this

> ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100;

But I just want to know is there a way to set the value of Auto Increment while creating the table?
 Somthing like this?

> CREATE TABLE Persons (
>  
>        ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 100,
>  
>        LastName
>   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>  
>        FirstName varchar(255),
>        Address varchar(255), 
>        PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
> )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can do it while creating the table as

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
     ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     FirstName varchar(255),
     Address varchar(255),
     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ->      ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->      LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ->      FirstName varchar(255),
    ->      Address varchar(255),
    ->      PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    -> )AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into Persons (LastName) values ('CCC');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from Persons ;
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+
| ID  | LastName | FirstName | Address |
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+
| 100 | CCC      | NULL      | NULL    |
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  CREATE TABLE Persons (
         ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
         FirstName varchar(255),
         Address varchar(255),
         PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```